# Angular: ngModel Interpolation returns NaN in input text box. How to show number

Tags: node.js, json, angular, typescript

I'm returning an object from NodeJs/Mongo with some keys that have values with numbers. I'm using interpolation to show these values in an Angular template, a form specifically. The number values are showing up in the text boxes as 'NaN'.

I'm using Angular 8 and a NodeJS Express server. I've got a mongo database and an entry like the one below.

I'm attempting to show these values in several text input boxes using [ngModel] so clients can edit these values. However, when I use interpolation to show the values in the template, I get NAN as a value

this shows NaN in the text box.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="videoOffsets.prores-23976">23.976</label>
     <input type="number" class="form-control" name="videoOffsets"
                    [ngModel]="suite?.videoOffsets?.prores-23976">
</div>
```

RETURNED OBJECT FROM NODE / MONGO

```
{
    "scope": [
        "Mixing"
    ],
    "_id": "5d4d00827c213e60b8ed7c7w",
    "name": "4",
    "type": "audio",
    "videoOffsets": {
        "prores-23976": 2,
        "prores-24": 4,
        "prores-25": 13,
        "prores-2997": 11,
        "dnxhd-23976": 5,
        "dnxhd-24": 7,
        "dnxhd-25": 3,
        "dnxhd-2997": 1,
        "h264-23976": 22,
        "h264-24": 8,
        "h264-25": 31,
        "h264-2997": 5
    }
}
```

Comment: you got what you were looking for in the answer below?

Answer (score 3):

the name of the field has a `-` which is causing this...

Change the **old way** (suite?.videoOffsets?.prores-23976):

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="videoOffsets"
                [ngModel]="suite?.videoOffsets?.prores-23976">
```

into this new way (suite?.videoOffsets['prores-23976']):

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="videoOffsets"
                [ngModel]="suite?.videoOffsets['prores-23976']">
```

as showed in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crv9lt) also

Comment: this is great, thanks. I stumbled upon this as well. Confusing to say the least. Thanks so much for the help

Comment: You're welcome, kindly accept the answer so that others can benefit from it in the future as well, Thanks

Comment: This - thing helped me i made a variable and passed that and it worked perfectly fine Thanks @AkberIqbal